# Ploting barplot differently in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
> example
  col1 col2 col3
1   -1    1   -1
2    0   -1    3
3    1   10   -1
```

and I want to plot a barplot and using row 3 as an example, I do `barplot(example[3,])`. This works perfectly. However, I want to flip the value and add more color -- specifically, I want:

- if the value is negative (i.e., -1 in row 3), I want to flip it into +1 and color red when plotting the boxplot. (but note that there are +1 value in the row already and we don't want to color that in red)
- if the value is >= +10, color the column green  in the boxplot

How can I do the above?

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(col1 = c(-1, 0, 1), col2 = c(1, -1, 10), col3 = c(-1, 
3, -1)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Be careful your syntax `barplot(example[3,])` isn't correct. It should be `barplot(example[,3])`.

Comment: @RémiCoulaud but I want to plot row 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a complet solution using only base R :

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(-1, 0, 1),
                     col2 = c(1, -1, 10),
                     col3 = c(-1, 3, -1)),
                row.names = c(NA, 3L),
                class = "data.frame")

# apply conditions on the matrix to color your plot
# If I well understand your demand, it is to have specific color with
# respect to specific condition. Multiply by 2 is to have different factor
  level

color <- (df >= 10) * 2 + (df < 0) + 1

# to swap -1 to +1 do that :
df[df < 0] <- df[df < 0] + 2

# set color as wishes
color <- matrix(c("black", "red", "green")[color], nrow = nrow(color), ncol = ncol(color), byrow = F)

# plot the vector we want
barplot(df[,3], col = color[,3])
```

**EDIT 1**

To plot the row 3 you can use this trick with transposition function `t()` :

```
barplot(t(df)[, 3], col = t(color)[, 3])
```

Comment: why is the condition `(df >= 10) * 2 + (df < 0) + 1` ? Like why are we multiplying by 2?

Comment: I hope my comment inside the code will help you to understand what I'm doing